# Voevodsky's proof in any characteristic (for motivic and Chow)

Tags: motivic-cohomology, localization, ag.algebraic-geometry

Regarding the published version of "Motivic cohomology groups are isomorphic to higher Chow groups in any characterstic" (IMRN) available at:

http://imrn.oxfordjournals.org/content/2002/7/351.full.pdf

I would appreciate any elucidation on the following two points:

**(1)** a short assertion is made on the second page whose proof is not entirely clear to me

and

**(2)** how this assertion factors into the proof of Theorem 1.

**For (1)** the short assertion is (from page 2, second paragraph from top):

For any smooth scheme $X$ (of finite type) over a field $k$, $x$ a point of $X$ and $k_0$ the subfield of constants of $k$, there exists a smooth variety $X_0$ over $k_0$  and a point $x_0$ on $X_0$ such that the local rings $O_{X, x}$ and $O_{X_0, x_0}$ are isomorphic.

As noted, the dimension of $X_0$ may be larger than that of $X$. Here is an example I worked out that I think illustrates the principle of the proof:

**Example**. Let $k  = \mathbb{F}_p(t), X = \mathbb{A}^1_k$ with parameter $T$, and let $x$ correspond to $(T-0)$. Then $k_0 = \mathbb{F}_p$ and put $X_0 = \mathbb{A}^2_{k_0}$ with  parameters $u, v$. Then via $u\mapsto T, v\mapsto t$, and $x_0$ corresponding to $(u-0)$, we have the desired isomorphism of local rings. Note that the residue fields of the local rings are $\mathbb{F}_p(t)$ and $\mathbb{F}_p(v)$, respectively.

**In general** (*assuming $k$ is absolutely finitely generated, i.e. is finitely generated over its prime field*): since the question is local, we assume $X$ affine: $X = Spec(A)$ with $A = k[T_1, \ldots, T_n]/I$. Then take a transcendence basis $t_1, \ldots, t_r$ of $k$ over $k_0$. Then it seems that $X_0$ is built from $T_1, \ldots, T_n, t_1, \ldots, t_r$, but I haven't worked this out in general.

**Problem**: what if $k$ does not have finite transcendence degree over $k_0$? In the absolutely finitely generated case, if $F$ is the prime field of $k$, then $k_0$ is a finite extension of $F$ and $tr.deg_F(k) = tr.deg_{k_0}(k)$.

**As for (2)**, the part that is not clear to me is when one passes from $X$ to $X_0$ in the course of the proof of the above cited paper (for example, in Prop 4).

NB: the above cited assertion is *not* included in the preprint http://www.math.uiuc.edu/K-theory/378/allagree.pdf

Cf. the sentence directly after Corollary 2 on page 1 of this preprint

Comment: I removed the newly created tag 'algebraic' since it seems to be created in error and in any case would be too unspecific as a tag. 

Comment: Voevodsky's statement (1) is plainly false if $k$ is not of finite transcendence degree over $k_0$ ($k$ itself then cannot be of the form $O_{X,x}$). However, it is nonetheless true that if $\mathbb{Z}(q)\simeq\mathbb{Z}^{FS}(q)$ over a perfect field $k_0$, then this automatically holds over any field extension $k$ of $k_0$. This is because these sheaves over $Sm/k$ (and the canonical map between them) are pulled back from $Sm/k_0$. Ultimately this is because any cycle on an inverse limit of schemes comes from one of the schemes in the diagram. I'll try to write a more detailed answer later.

Comment: Marc: Thanks for your comment. What do you intend to show by saying a field is not of the form of a local ring in your first sentence? Perhaps you meant something about the residue fields? In general, residue fields of local rings can have infinite transcendence degree over the prime field. – Ivan 2 mins ago 


Comment: @Ivan: Take $X=Spec(k)$ so that $O_{X,x}=k$. According to Voevodsky's statement there should exist $X_0$ smooth of finite type over $k_0$ whose function field is $k$. So the transcendence degree of $k$ must be finite.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Voevodsky's statement (1) is plainly false if $k$ is not of finite transcendence degree over $k_0$. For then the fraction field of any $O_{X,x}$ is of infinite transcendence degree over $k_0$ whereas the fraction field of $O_{X_0,x_0}$ always has finite transcendence degree over $k_0$.

But anyway here's a more detailed justification of this reduction step. Assume that $k_0$ is a perfect field and that we've already established the equivalence of motivic cohomology and higher Chow groups for schemes in $Sm/k_0$. Let $k_0\subset k$ be any field extension. We'd like to show that

$$H^{n,q}(X)\cong CH^q(X,2q-n)$$

for any $X\in Sm/k$ and any $n,q\in\mathbb Z$.

Any $X\in Sm/k$ can be written as a cofiltered limit of smooth $k_0$-schemes of finite type as follows. It suffices to do it for $X=Spec(k)$ itself, since any smooth scheme of finite type over $S=lim S_\alpha$ comes from a smooth scheme of finite type over some $S_\alpha$ (by EGA4 Prop. 17.7.8). Now $Spec(k)$ is the limit of the schemes $Spec(L)$ where $L$ ranges over the finitely generated subextensions of $k/k_0$, and if $L=k_0(x_1,\dotsc,x_n)$, $Spec(L)$ is the limit of the nonempty open subsets of $Spec(k_0[x_1,\dotsc,x_n])$, which are eventually smooth over $k_0$ since $k_0$ is perfect (see EGA4, Cor. 17.15.13). So in this way we can view any $X\in Sm/k$ as a pro-object $(X_\alpha)$ in $Sm/k_0$.

The key is that both motivic cohomology and higher Chow groups are "continuous" with respect to such inverse limits, i.e., they transform them into colimits:

$$H^{n,q}(X)\cong colim_\alpha H^{n,q}(X_\alpha),\quad CH^q(X,2q-n)\cong colim_\alpha CH^q(X_\alpha,2q-n).$$

The former is Lemma 3.9 in [Lecture Notes on Motivic Cohomology](http://www.claymath.org/library/monographs/cmim02.pdf). I don't know a reference for the latter, but it should be easy. Since $X_\alpha\in Sm/k_0$ we know that $H^{n,q}(X_\alpha)\cong CH^{q}(X_\alpha,2q-n)$, whence the desired isomorphism in the colimit.

(Of course, if you analyze the proof, you'll find out that this isomorphism between motivic cohomology and higher Chow groups comes from a zig-zag of maps defined at the level of complexes of presheaves, so you've really shown that $\mathbb Z(q)$ and $\mathbb Z^{FS}(q)$ are quasi-isomorphic in the Zariski topology over $Sm/k$.)